# Domain prefix in squid - bypassing rules

Tags: linux, squid

I have successfully setup squid service and start to block domain :

```
acl blocked dstdomain "/mypath/to/blockedlist"
http_access deny blocked
```

in "blockedlist" file i have:

```
site1.pl
site2.pl
```

When i run browser and go to site1.pl it is blocked but, when i add "www" and go to  www.site1.pl i bypass deny rule and can run this site. I dont want to duplicate domains by simply add second versions with www in my blockedlist file. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using squid 2.2 or greater, and you need to prefix the domain with a dot, so instead of `site1.pl`, you would use `.site1.pl`.

As stated here on the [ACL](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#Squid_doesn.27t_match_my_subdomains) page:

`Squid-2.2 and later needs to have domains prefixed by a dot`